# Connect ArcGIS 10.6 to Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, oracle-dbms, database

I want to connect ArcGIS 10.6 to an Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition. However, I found different informations on the Esri websites on how to do so.

1. I followed this website (http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/connect-oracle.htm) and executed it step by step. All worked fine, as far as I can tell. However, I got an Error message telling me that:

> Failed to connect to specified server. Do you want to continue? Cannot
>   connect to database because the database client software failed to
>   load. Be sure the database client software is installed and configured
>   correctly.

2. I found this ESRI website https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/get-started/introduction/whats-new-in-arcgis.htm where it states that "Oracle Instant client will not work.", directly contradicting the instructions on website 1.

So what is right, respectivley, how can I connect ArcGIS 10.6 to Oracle 12c?

Comment: There is no contradiction. This refers to a special case of connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to establish a connection. 2 things I changed seemed to have made the difference.

1. I installed the 64bit Instant Client of Oracle, assuming that on Windows 10 64bit and ArcGIS 64bit that would be the correct choice - which it isn't. For my setup, you have to install the 32bit version of the Oracle Instant Client.
2. I changed the location of the tnsnames.ora file from 
   C:/oracle/instantclient_12_2
   to 
   C:/oracle/instantclient_12_2/network/admin

Comment: 64-bit Instant Client would be correct for a 64-bit client (like ArcGIS Pro or Server), but you used a 32-bit client (ArcMap).

Comment: I tried both Clients, but only when I use the 32bit Version I can connect from ArcMap  @Vince. Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: ArcMap is a 32-bit client.